# Linux RHEL7.3 X11 Java GUI forwarding issue

Tags: java, linux, awt, x11, rhel7

The GUI issue happens when I use X11 forwarding from **Linux RHEL 7.3** to Windows 8.1/10. AWT labels, buttons, menus are not displayed. And there is no the issue when **Linux RHEL 6.8** or/and SWING is used. What could be wrong with **Linux RHEL 7.3**?

[image]

**AWTDemo.java :**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class AWTDemo extends Frame
{
    AWTDemo()
    {
        setTitle("AWT Demo");
        setBounds(200,200, 200, 100);
        Button b=new Button("BUTTON");
        b.setBounds(50,100,50,50);
        add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {dispose();}});
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        AWTDemo wnd = new AWTDemo();
    }
}
```

**SWINGDemo.java:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SWINGDemo extends JFrame
{

    SWINGDemo()
    {
        super("SWING Demo");
        setBounds(200,200, 200, 100);
        JButton b = new JButton("BUTTON");
        add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SWINGDemo wnd = new SWINGDemo();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not starting on the event dispatching thread (`EventQueue.invokeLater`). For the rest: `awt` is so java-2-ish. Brrr.

Comment: It is demo/example/test. "EventQueue.invokeLater" is not related to the mentioned above problem.